# Overload Single Equals in swift

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading

I have a strange situation where I can't seem to get single equals to overload

This works fine:

```
public func /=<T: ConvertibleUnit>(inout left: T, right: Int) {
    left.value = (left.value / Double(right))
}
```

As soon as i change it to:

```
public func =<T: ConvertibleUnit>(inout left: T, right: Int) {
    left.value = Double(right)
}
```

I get the error:

**Operator implementation without matching operator declaration**

Is there something crazy obvious I'm missing?

I played around with infix and it didn't seem to do much.  I'm assuming somehow its interpreting = wrong?

Comment: I can't remember for sure, but I recall reading somewhere that Swift doesn't allow you to overload the `=` operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No dice, I’m afraid.  From the [language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418)

> The tokens =, ->, //, /*, */, ., the prefix operators <, &, and ?, the infix operator ?, and the postfix operators >, !, and ? are reserved. These tokens can’t be overloaded, nor can they be used as custom operators.

Instead, if you want `ConvertibleUnit` to always be creatable from an `Int`, give the protocol an `init(_ val: Int)` method so people can write `let unit = T(42)`.  Or maybe even consider having it conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.

Generally, the preferred style in Swift is not to have automatic/implicit conversions between different types.  This is why, for example, you must cast an `Int` to a `Double` before you can add it to another `Double`.

Of course, you can write things like this:

```
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Double) -> Double {
    return Double(lhs) + rhs
}

let i = 1
let f = 1.2
i + f   // = 2.2
```

but this is in general not considered good practice.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html),

> It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=). Only the compound assignment operators can be overloaded. Similarly, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c) cannot be overloaded.

You could possibly create a new operator using `infix`, but sadly you just can't overload '='.